# JOTM getTransactionManager().getTransaction() return null

Tags: java, spring, jta, xa, jotm

I'm using spring, oracle and jotm (in tomcat) to use 2PC commit.
Below is the spring configuration.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="defaultOperation"
        expression="execution(* jatis.avantrade.foundation.model.engine.*.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="defaultTrxAdvice" pointcut-ref="defaultOperation" />
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="defaultTrxAdvice" transaction-manager="trxManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="check*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="select*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="count*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="search*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="list*" read-only="true" />
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<bean id="txImpl" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JotmFactoryBean" />




<bean id="trxManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txImpl" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="txImpl" />
</bean>
```

The questions is when I call `getTransactionManager().getTransaction()` using JOTM object, it returns null.

```
Current cur = (Current) ContextHelper.getApplicationContext()
                    .getBean("txImpl");
            try {
                log.error("cur : " cur.getTransactionManager().getTransaction());
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to use [Apache TomEE](http://openejb.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) which is Tomcat with the TransactionManager already integrated.  The write a simple Spring factory bean to hand Spring the TransactionManager and UserTransaction.

Both can be looked up from JNDI:

- `java:comp/TransactionManager`
- `java:comp/UserTransaction`

That factory would just replace the one from the above config:

```
<bean id="txImpl" class="org.foo.MyTransactionFactoryBean" />
```

Though, it's very likely Spring already has a factory bean for looking up the TransactionManager via these names.